# How to query in django datetimefield with default timezone.now for a specific day?

Tags: django, django-timezone

I have a model `Game` with datetimefield set to default timezone.now().

```
class Game(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to query how many games were played on a specific day. I have tried following command and that works fine.

```
games = Game.objects.filter(time=timezone.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

But now I want to query Games with filter set to a specific day, let say timezone.now - 1 day. I have tried different variations of `timezone.localtime` and `timezone.localdate` and they yield a ValueError.

```
>>> timezone.localtime(datetime.datetime.now(), timezone.get_default_timezone())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/savi/python-environments/comments/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py", line 207, in localtime
    raise ValueError("localtime() cannot be applied to a naive datetime")
ValueError: localtime() cannot be applied to a naive datetime
```

I have looked at different questions and other [sites](https://www.fullstackpython.com/django-utils-timezone-examples.html) and none have suggested any approach for what I am trying to do. Maybe I am not looking at the right places. If someone can guide me through this, I will really appreciate that, Thanks in advance and a very happy new Year.

**EDIT**
I have tried the solution as suggested.

```
>>> time = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
>>> time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
'2019-12-31'
>>> games = Game.objects.filter(time=time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
/home/savi/python-environments/comments/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1427: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Game.time received a naive datetime (2019-12-31 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
```

RuntimeWarning)

And also

```
>>> games = Game.objects.filter(time=timezone.now().date())
/home/savi/python-environments/comments/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1369: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Game.time received a naive datetime (2020-01-01 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
```

**END OF EDIT**

my settings.py file

```
# TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But now I want to query Games with filter set to a specific day, let
>   say timezone.now - 1 day

You can use [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

```
games = Game.objects.filter(time = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)))
```

**Edit:**
for specific day filter you can use `__date` when filtering

```
>>> time = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
>>> time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
'2019-12-31'
>>> games = Game.objects.filter(time__date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Comment: the problem is this is matching the exact date and time, I just want to match the day. See the edits in the questions

Comment: use __date when filtering

Comment: Thanks that did the job, I thought there was issues coming up because of the different timezone thing.